# Facebook : How to prove publish_pages right when Webhook only runs in Pushlish mode?

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-requests

Permissions required are publish_pages.

I need to get "Webhook Event" from facebook to get the "comment_id" of the guest when commenting on the page, then reply back by comment_id (equivalent to prove publish_pages)

But "Webhook Event" only works when App Developer is in Publish mode. But the right to post on the page without approval is only allowed to operate in Developer mode.

How do Facebook reviewers understand that?

Comment: Use account test

Comment: It should work fine in dev mode, as long as all users involved have a role in the app.